# Simple php $message display center?

Tags: php, html

How do I display my image on the center of my page I tried

```
<center><?php
        }
        else
        {
            $form = true;
            $message = 'The username or password you entered are not good.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $form = true;
    }
    if($form)
    {
?></center>
```

But it didn't work..

Comment: does it display the message?

Comment: Don't use <center> tags, use CSS to position your output. Additionally, restructure your code so that it's obvious what the conditionals are doing. I can't see the if statements in here, and you run a high risk of something failing and the <center> tags not even being output in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php } else {
      $form = true;
      $message = '<div style="text-align: center;>The username or password you entered are not good.</div>';
     }
    } else {
        $form = true;
    }
    if($form)
    {
?>
```

However, you should be doing this in your CSS file.

Comment: +1 for css. You could use this `$message = '<div class="center">...</div>` and in your css use this: `.center{text-align:center;}`

Answer (score 1):

Add inline CSS style like below

```
$message = '<span style = "text-align:center">The username or password you entered are not good.</span>';
    echo $message;
```

Comment: Inline css should be avoided if possible. All CSS styling should be gathered in CSS files.

Comment: Yes, it should be avoided, I just wrote it here to demonstrate the use.

Answer (score 1):

Code you posted is syntactically broken.

For centering in HTML you can use style like this one:

```
<div style='text-align: center'>Your message</div>
```

For print text from PHP to HTML output, use `echo`:

```
echo $message;
```

Together:

```
<div style='text-align: center'><?php echo $message; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the STYLE area above the PHP

```
<style type="text/css">
    body,td,th {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```